# Save captured screenshot in certain path javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have one issue, finally solve with browser tab screenshot capturing. But how save captured images in certain folder path, only with vanilla JS without back-end. For now, by default saves in download folder

```
const url = 'http://local.requestmapper.com/api/user/';

document.getElementById('logout').addEventListener("click", logout);
document.getElementById('takess').addEventListener("click", takess);

function takess() {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function (canvas) {

        var filename = getFormattedTime();
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.href = canvas;
        a.download = filename + ".jpg";
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
          
    });
}

function getFormattedTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var d = today.getDate();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var mi = today.getMinutes();
    return y + "_" + m + d + "_" + h + mi;
}
```

user.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="logout">Log Out</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="takess">Take screenshot</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```